# Where do you place your code when adding a new category for a new class?

Tags: objective-c

If I need to declare and define a category, lets say I have:

```
@interface Calculator (Trig)

-(double) sin;
-(double) cos;
-(double) tan;

@end
```

And I want to implement and define this methods, where should I place them in the calculator files? I mean what is the proper way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

One common style is to put categories in files named `ClassName+CategoryName.h` (and .m), e.g. `Calculator+Trig.h` (and .m). But use whatever style you prefer, really. I personally find it beneficial sometimes to have multiple related categories in the same file.

Comment: thanks. do if I want to keep it in the same file, I will declare the category in the top of the .m file, and then define the methods in the same `implementation` file as the `Calculator`? @tom

Comment: Depends on your use case. If there is a category that you want to use which is private to the implementation of `Calculator`, then you can declare it in the `.m`, and implement it in the same `@implementation` block as your main class. This is actually a common pattern for creating "private" methods. In this case, usually you would just use the empty category name (e.g. `@interface Calculator ()`).